# Why is NuGet.exe pack ignoring the Configuration=Release parameter?

Tags: nuget

Using nuget.exe to package an application, I specify Release as the configuration, but it fails with "Make sure the project has been built." because it's looking in the Debug folder, not the Release folder:

```
NuGet.exe pack "C:\dev\Test\WpfApp1.csproj" -OutputDirectory "C:\dev\a\packages\" -Properties Configuration=Release

Attempting to build package from 'WpfApp1.csproj'.

Unable to find 'C:\dev\Test\bin\Debug\WpfApp1.exe'. Make sure the project has been built.
```

Why?

Answer (score 5):

After much trial and error I figured it out. Spot the difference?:

```
NuGet.exe pack "C:\dev\Test\WpfApp1.csproj" -OutputDirectory "C:\dev\a\packages" -Properties Configuration=Release

Attempting to build package from 'WpfApp1.csproj'.

Packing files from 'C:\dev\Test\bin\Release'.
```

Yes, a back slash at the end of the path of the OutputDirectory parameter caused it to choose Debug instead of Release. No wonder it took me 4 hours to narrow it down from the failing TFS Nuget Packager step. Not funny.

Comment: Thank you, that saved me a lot of trouble. NuGet is a pretty terrible tool considering its the official package manager for the MS ecosystem...